# Easiest way to make complex div with waves

Tags: html, css, svg, adobe-illustrator

I would like to create divs with complex waves, I'm coming across a lot of tutorials and I tried a lot of things but I can not do it. What is the best way to make waves and the background goes around and stops at the wave? What is the best/simplest way, I heard about the SVG but no skill with that. Is it complicated to realize? I wish I could draw curves and change the background accordingly as on this WordPress theme:
https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/theme-releases/shape-dividers

I wish I could do that:
http://www.zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/22/jr0r.png

I have to learn SVG ? or use illustrator, too complicated directly in CSS if I have several waves. A software like an illustrator to do that for free with SVG exist?

and then do the rest of my style with bootstrap 4 etc? ...thank you

Comment: SVG for free? Inkscape. Google first, StackOverflow last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can do this using Perlin noise. However you can do it also by setting a number of points with successive x and random y on the svg canvas, and connecting the points with Béziers.

```js
let w = 1000;
let h = 300;
svg.setAttributeNS(null,"viewBox",`0 0 ${w} ${h}`)
let n = 18; //number of points
let points = [];// the points array used to draw the curve

// add points to the points array
for(let x=0; x <= w; x+= w/n){
  let y = h - Math.random()*h;
  points.push({x:x,y:y})
}


// a function to connect all the points in the points array with beziers
function  connect(points) {    
   let d = "";// the d attribute for the path
   // move to the first point of the array
   d+= `M${points[0].x}, ${points[0].y}`;
    //build the path
    for (var i = 1; i < points.length - 2; i++) {
      var cp = {};
      cp.x = (points[i].x + points[i + 1].x) / 2;
      cp.y = (points[i].y + points[i + 1].y) / 2;
      
      d+=`Q${points[i].x},${points[i].y} ${cp.x},${cp.y}`
    }
    //the last curve
    let index = points.length-2
   d+=`Q${points[index].x},${points[index].y} ${points[index + 1].x},${points[index + 1].y}`;
   //close the path
   d+=`V${h}H0z`
    return d;
  }
//set the attribute `d` for the wave
wave.setAttributeNS(null,"d",connect(points))
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" >
  <path id="wave" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Hello, this script is magic, I would never have managed to do that. Just a big problem. The shape of the curve changes each time the page is reloaded. What if I want to make a static curve? Thank you

Comment: In this case you hardcode the values for the points. Alternatively if you see a curve that you like you can open the inspector and copy the svg element and use it in your html

Answer (score 0):

I tried this before, just by using an image as border. You can create an image with a wavy border and play with transparency so you get the effect you need.